# Reverse for 'hire_a_crew' not found. 'hire_a_crew' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I keep on getting a NoReverseMatch at / error when i run my project

here is the app level url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from justproduceit_project import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

app_name = 'create'

urlpatterns = [
    path('equipment_categories/', views.EquipmentCategoriesListView.as_view(), name='equipment_categories'),
    path('rent_equipment/', views.EquipmentListView.as_view(), name='equipment_home_page'),
    path('equipment/<slug>/', views.EquipmentDetailView.as_view(), name='equipment_detail'),
    path('add_to_cart/<slug>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    path('remove_from_cart/<slug>/', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('hire_a_crew/', views.CrewListView.as_view(), name='hire_a_crew'),
    path('start_a_project/', views.ProjectListView.as_view(), name='start_a_project'),
]
```

here is the settings level urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('learn/', include('learn.urls')),
    path('create/', include('create.urls', namespace='create')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

here is the template that is throwing the error

```
<div class="dropdown-menu col-lg-12 text-center" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <h6 class="dropdown-header"><b>Hire a</b></h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'hire_a_crew' %}">Crew</a> 
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Director</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Producer</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Writer</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cinematographer</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'equipment_home_page' %}" role="button">Rent equipment</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'start_a_project' %}" role="button">Start a project</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a namespace/app_name to your app's urls, you need use this prefix this every time you use reverse or the url tag

```
{% url 'create:hire_a_crew' %}
```